# CakePHP pagination limit helper

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to change the limit of records from view file.

In view I tried:

```
 localhost/project/users/index/limit:25
 localhost/project/users/index/limit:10
```

But no success, it always shows 10 records as specified in controller

```
public function index() {
 $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array(),
    'limit' => 10
 );
 $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Recipe');
 $this->set(compact('data'));
);
```

Comment: Then you shouldn't set a limit in your settings. Or only set the limit if there is no param for it passed via URL.

Comment: @mark but other parameters like `order:` are overridden even if they are set, why not limit?

Comment: That is a good question: What fields can be overwritten and which can't. Probably order because it usally is built via "sort" and "direction". I usually don't use Paginator->settings, but $paginate directly.

Comment: @mark I was making some tests to answer this question and I found that if you set the `maxLimit` parameter then the `limit` parameter can be overwritten otherwise not. Can you explain the reason of this behavior?

Comment: No, not exactly, the maxLimit just sets the maximum allowed limit. This is usually something around 100 to avoid attacks where you can make the server fail due to too large datasets requested.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the Component options in a view file as Component is a part of Controller in MVC. If you need to change the 'limit' option of Paginator component you should do that in controller and never in a view file.

Comment: he doesnt try to set it in the view file. He meant those URLs as *links* he can click on..

Answer (score -1):

Set your default settings global in your contoller.

```
class YourController extends AppController
{
   var $paginate = array( 'limit' => 10 );
   public function index()
   {
   //...
   }
}
```

Now your url parameters should work. Consider setting `maxlimit`, too.
When setting `limit` within your index function you override the url parameter.